# Reality Composer Tap Trigger issue

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm new to Augmented Reality and I was going with Apple docs and WWDC videos to create my scene using Reality Composer simple blue ball that orbits around a white ball when I tap on blue ball but the tap trigger is not working when running on real device (iPhone 13) but working in Reality Composer, and here is the `.rcproject` url: https://filebin.net/asekvc7p9wt9ube8

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let arVi = ARView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ar = try! orbits.loadScene()
        arVi.scene.anchors.append(ar)

        scannerView.addSubview(arVi)
        arVi.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        arVi.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        arVi.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        arVi.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        arVi.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: Belal, your link says: `The transfer you requested has been deleted`.

Comment: i added a new link for rcproject @AndyJazz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the issue that the ArView was added to a scannerView which was a normal UIImageView deleting that image and adding the ArVIew to the main View make it work

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let arVi = ARView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ar = try! orbits.loadScene()
    arVi.scene.anchors.append(ar)

    self.view.addSubview(arVi)
    arVi.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    arVi.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
    arVi.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
    arVi.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    arVi.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### There might be five possible problems:

---

1. You're trying to play behaviors on iOS Simulator:

   - Reality Composer Tap-behaviors can be run on a real device only.

---

2. Collision boxes' interference:

   - After up-scaling, collision boxes of models intersect.

---

3. Behaviors assigned incorrectly:

   - Check the Affected Objects of Trigger and Action Sequence.

---

4. You do not follow Swift's naming convention:

   - Rename lowercased enum `orbits` to `Orbits`.

---

5. Try not a Custom Behavior:

   - Choose `Tap & Flip` behavior, then replace its Action with `Orbit`.

Comment: i do run the project on a real device and the affected objects are correct the trigger tap is assigned to the blue ball so when i tap on it, it orbits around the white ball

Comment: i do check everything but nothing works for now